# Swagger2 too many the same annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I integrate swagger2 to springboot project, because all of my endpoints authorization is by OAuth2, so I need to add Authorization header to every method, like the following code:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({     
    @ApiImplicitParam(paramType="header",name="Authorization",dataType="String",required=true, value="Bearer {access-token}")
})
```

These same annotations are too many, can I have some ways to refactor them?

Swagger2 Docket code:

```
@Bean
public Docket createRestApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .ignoredParameterTypes(TokenInfo.class, HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.xxx.yyy.resource"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: So you want to test your api through `access_token` from `swagger-ui` isn't it?

Comment: yes, I need access_token to test all endpoints at swagger-ui page. Actually, if only my test, I don't need to add it, but test team want it.

Comment: So can you provide your docket config code?

Comment: Did it worked ? @Liu

Comment: It works fine, thank you. sorry for reply delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spend couple of days to find out the solution. Here I give you the docket config for `access_token`. Configure a global parameter, can say common parameters (`access_token`) that includes every end-point.So you don't need to include `@ApiImplicitParams` to every end-point. Probable docket configuration given below (later your can change of your own for **api info**).

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.xxx.yyy.resource"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .globalOperationParameters(commonParameters())
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .ignoredParameterTypes(TokenInfo.class, HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class)
            .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
            .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()));
}


private List<Parameter> commonParameters() {
    List<Parameter> parameters = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
    parameters.add(new ParameterBuilder()
            .name("access_token")
            .description("token for authorization")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
            .parameterType("query")
            .required(true)
            .build());

    return parameters;
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
            "My REST API",
            "Some custom description of API.",
            "API TOS",
            "Terms of service",
            "myeaddress@company.com",
            "License of API",
            "API license URL");
    return apiInfo;
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
            = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return Lists.newArrayList(
            new SecurityReference("AUTHORIZATION", authorizationScopes));
}

private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("AUTHORIZATION", "access_token", "header");
}
```

Just paste the code and try from `swagger-ui` and let me know the status.

Comment: You should also accept the answer for fellow users of stackoverflow. @Liuguanghua